# App works fine when debuging on test device but not in the release apk , it does not get the post.class variables from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My application has posts in activities, the post has an image and like button and star count and share button. Everything is working when debugging to the test device, but not in the published version.
After publishing the app on google store, all the variables under the post.class are not received/displayed (everything using *post.get* like for example *post.getimage()* is not getting the values from firebase database. on other hand, the values that are stored outside the post are received (for example I have a separate *starcount* node and I'm getting the value of the childcount and it's working fine). 
I have tried all the possible solutions but nothing worked:
Updated the app with SHA release key (upload key) then generated the signed apk(aab), all of the three SHA (debug , release and app signing key) are saved under my firebase project fingerprint.
I also checked the firebase database rules.
I changed some variable in the post.class from public to private

I downloaded the APK directly on the device and also it's not working . it works perfect on the test device. Appreciate if anyone can help and many thanks in advance.

this is the post.class

```
// [START post_class]

@IgnoreExtraProperties

public class Post {

private String image;
public String uid;
public String author;
public String title;
public String body;
public String videoLink;
private int starCount = 0;
private int starCount2 = 0;
private Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

//shares
private String ntDeeplink;
private int ntNumShares = 0 ;
private String postID;

public Post() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
}

public Post(String image, String uid, String author, String title, String body, String videoLink) {
    this.image = image;
    this.uid = uid;
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.videoLink = videoLink;


}

//note 2 constructor here were icrease instead of one , and the above one in connectedto some methods already


public Post(int starCount, Map<String, Boolean> stars, String ntDeeplink, int ntNumShares, String ntPostID) {
    this.starCount = starCount;
    this.stars = stars;
    this.ntDeeplink = ntDeeplink;
    this.ntNumShares = ntNumShares;
    this.postID = postID;
}

public Post(int starCount2) {
    this.starCount2 = starCount2;
}

// [START post_to_map]   ....this and bindToPost(if there is a view) replace the method of populateViewHolder
// but only for non Storage Items like Images
@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    result.put("image",image);
    result.put("uid", uid);
    result.put("author", author);
    result.put("title", title);
    result.put("body", body);
    result.put("videoLink", videoLink);
    result.put("starCount", starCount);
    result.put("starCount2", starCount2);
    result.put("stars", stars);
    //numShares also created int the contants
    result.put("ntNumShares", ntNumShares);
    result.put("ntDeeplink", ntDeeplink);
    result.put("postID", postID);

    return result;
}

//shares

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}

public String getVideoLink() {
    return videoLink;
}

public void setVideoLink(String videoLink) {
    this.videoLink = videoLink;
}

public int getStarCount() {
    return starCount;
}

public void setStarCount(int starCount) {
    this.starCount = starCount;
}

public int getStarCount2() {
    return starCount2;
}

public void setStarCount2(int starCount2) {
    this.starCount2 = starCount2;
}

public Map<String, Boolean> getStars() {
    return stars;
}

public void setStars(Map<String, Boolean> stars) {
    this.stars = stars;
}

public String getNtDeeplink() {
    return ntDeeplink;
}

public void setNtDeeplink(String ntDeeplink) {
    this.ntDeeplink = ntDeeplink;
}

public int getNtNumShares() {
    return ntNumShares;
}

public void setNtNumShares(int ntNumShares) {
    this.ntNumShares = ntNumShares;
}

public String getPostID() {
    return postID;
}

public void setPostID(String postID) {
    this.postID = postID;
}


// [END post_to_map]
```

}
// [END post_class]

and this is for example how I'm getting image in the activity

```
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            final Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            final DatabaseReference postRef = mPostReference;
            final DatabaseReference postRefLikes = mPostReferenceLikes;


            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            //Image
            String image = null;
            if (post != null) {
                image = post.getImage();
            }
            Picasso.with(HbDetailActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.likes_hl_gr).into(hbDActivityPostImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question after two days of searching:
What was creating this problem is Proguard. When creating the signed APK, Proguard clean any unused codes or classes ..in my case  post.class has been deleted mistakenly by Proguard:

The solution:

- I put the post.class and other classes that I want to make sure Proguard doesn't delete them under one package (models), you can put them under different packages, but you need to list all of them under Proguard rules as below:
- In may android studio project I opened proguard-rules.pro
- I put the below line to list and keep the classes from deleting when Proguard creates the signed APK(or aab)

  ```
  -keepclassmembers class com.mydomain.app.models.** {*;}
  ```

Where com.domain.app is the name of the package

Hope that will save someone time.

Comment: This was so helpful though for my case I used                                                     -keep class com.hamsoftug.cashflow.models.** {*;}